# Pandas Data Lookup by Value in Column and then Row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DF:

```
              Axis        G1        G2       G3         G4        G5  
0             NaN         ABC       DEF      GHI        KLM       NOP   
1             QRS          Y        Y        Y          N         N   
2             TUV          Y        Y        N          N         N   
3             WXZ          Y        Y        N          N         N   
4             ZAB          Y        Y        XX         N         Y   
5             CDE          Y        Y        N          N         Y   
6             FGH          Y        Y        Y          N         Y
```

I want to select the column by the value in row index 0 and then select the row by the string in the column called Axis.

For example, Column with row 0 = 'GHI' with axis 'ZAB' should return 'XX'.

I have tried:

```
DF.columns = DF.iloc(0)
```

And then filtering by row in column, but this generates errors even if I assign a value to Axis[0].  I am thinking there should filter the column by the value in Row[0] and then select the row by value of Axis.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing: if `GHI` is the column name, what is `G3`?

Comment: I noticed the same thing after I typed it.  I edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way. Just set your index as `Axis`, then rename columns to first row.

```
df = df.set_index('Axis').rename(columns=df.iloc[0])

df.loc['ZAB', 'GHI']  # 'XX'
```